# Jquery switch input values after click on link

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 inputs:

```
<form>

    <input type="text" name="address" id="address" value="">
    <input type="text" name="address2" id="address2" value="">

</form>

<a href="">switch addresses</a>
```

When I click on link, then address value will copy to address2 value and address2 value will copy to address value.

**Q:** How to basically switch inputs values **when I click on link**?

My knowledge:

```
//get
var bla = $('#address').val();
//set
$('#address2').val('bla');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('a').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var obj = { // create object
       "address" : $('#address').val(), // get the address value 
       "address2" : $('#address2').val() // get the address2 value 
    };
    $('#address').val(obj.address2); // set here
    $('#address2').val(obj.address); // set here
});
```

---

#### [Demo @ Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PLbCm/)

---

Answer (score 2):

Try to remove that quotes from `bla`, if you dont then it will be considered as a string,

```
var bla = $('#address').val();
$('#address2').val(bla);
```

Swapping,

```
$('a:contains("switch addresses")').click(function(){
    var tmp = $('#address').val();
    $('#address').val($('#address2').val())
    $('#address2').val(tmp);
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/U4PDH/)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for swapping two input field values:

```
var bla = $('#address').val();
$('#address').val($('#address2').val());
$('#address2').val(bla);
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qax4t/4/)**

Answer (score 1):

```
var bla = $('#address').val();
var cla = $('#address2').val();
$('#address2').val(bla);
$('#address').val(cla);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like below on hyperlink event :

```
var temp = $('#address2').val();

$('#address2').val($('#address').val(););

$('#address').val(temp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
$('a').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var add1= $('#address').val();
    var add2 = $('#address2').val();
    $('#address2').val(add1);
    $('#address').val(add2);
});
```